# Using jQuery Globalize to format / prefix a positive number with a '+' (plus)

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to prefix a positive number with a `+` using [jquery globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)?

For example, on a jqueryui.spinner, when you go to negative numbers they are all, of course, prefixed with a `-`.

I'd like to always prefix the positive numbers with a `+`.

Right now I'm using jquery globalize format of: `n` and it produces, for example: **2.03**

I'd like to achieve **+2.03**

I know I can hook into a change event and prefix it myself, but can this be done using only jquery globalize?